# What is the Affine Weyl Group?

Tags: group-theory

I would appreciate any information about the Affine Weyl Group, including references to good expositions on the topic. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group#Affine_Coxeter_groups)?..

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for more detail, such as presentation, properties and possibly some intuition.